# New to TypeScript, "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User[]' "

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

Why does TypeScript is yelling at me here?

```
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      dispatch(getUser(user));
    });
  }, [dispatch]);
```

*Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User[]'.*

*Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User[]'*

Redux

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface User {
  uid: string;
}

interface AuthState {
  user: User[];
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
  user: [],
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    
    getUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User[]>) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  getUser,
} = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: The `getUser` action takes a single parameter which is an array of `User` (`PayloadAction<User[]>`). Perhaps the dispatch call should be `if (user) dispatch(getUser([user]));`

Comment: This fixes the error for me but is this how i suppose to do it or is just a solution you gave me to something i did wrong?

Comment: It does seem odd to me that `getUser` accepts an array of `User` objects, but it also seems odd to me that `getUser` accepts any parameter at all rather than returning a `User`. If you're looking for a code review then that's another question!

Answer (score -2):

Because TS has determined that the result from your payload action *could* be `null`, so if the value of `user` could be null (which is typical if a user is logged out), you need to specify that in your interface:

```js
interface AuthState {
  user: User[] | null;
}
```

This would require the instance of AuthState to be initialized with user set to null. If you want to make user able to be initialized undefined, use the optional operator like so:

```js
interface AuthState {
  user?: User[] | null;
}
```

Also, you're setting the type of user to be an array of type User. Is that what you intended?

Comment: This is not correct, the `?` is for an optional parameter, i.e. it is either the type you give it or `undefined`

Comment: yep you're right. I'll update my answer